# Previously stored values, in a member vector, change after receiving new BSM

Tags: c++, omnet++, veins

I wrote an application for a vehicle in Veins as follows:

The header file:

```
class CarApp : public BaseWaveApplLayer
{
public:
  CarApp();
  ~ CarApp();
  void initialize(int stage);
  void finish();

protected:
  void handleSelfMsg(cMessage* msg);
  void onBSM(BasicSafetyMessage* bsm);

private:
  std::vector<Sender> senderVector_;
};
```

The implementation:

```
CarApp::CarApp() {}
CarApp::~CarApp() {}

void CarApp::initialize(int stage) {
  BaseWaveApplLayer::initialize(stage);
}

void CarApp::finish() {
  BaseWaveApplLayer::finish();
}

void handleSelfMsg(cMessage* msg) {
  BaseWaveApplLayer::handleSelfMsg(msg);
}

inline Sender* findSender(int senderId, std::vector<Sender>& senderVector) {
  for (auto sender : senderVector) {
    if (sender.getId() == senderId)
      return &sender;
  }
  return nullptr;
}

void onBSM(BasicSafetyMessage* bsm) {
  if (condition to check if this BSM is from a new sender) {
    auto sender = Sender(bsm->getSenderAddress(), other variable initializations);
    senderVector_.push_back(sender); // <- this is where I face the problem
  }
  else {
    // update other values in Sender object
  }
  // This part wasn't in the original MWE
  auto sender = findSender(id, senderVector_);
  // ... process members of "sender"
  delete(sender); // <-- this was the real culprit!
}
```

Sender class header:

```
class Sender
{
  Sender();
  explicit Sender(int id, Coord pos, Coord accel);

  private:
    int id_;
    Coord pos_;
    Coord accel_;
}
```

Sender class implementation:

```
Sender::Sender() {}
Sender::Sender(int id, Coord pos, Coord accel)
  : id_(id), pos_(pos), accel_(accel) {}
```

Whenever `CarApp` receives a BSM, the `onBSM()` function is run.

When I receive the first BSM, a new `Sender` object is created, initialized and pushed into `senderVector_`. However, when I receive the next BSM from either the same sender or any other, the previously stored `Sender` object gets corrupted with garbage values.

Also, `CarApp` crashes when a new `Sender` object is being pushed into `senderVector_`.

I am out of reasons for this to fail since it seems pretty simple to work as expected. Does anyone have any ideas why it is not?

**Edit 1:** removed references to Coord objects as suggested by @UnholySheep and @user6386155

**Edit 2:** I wrote a simple MWE that would work without the simulator, just to check the logic. It works flawlessly. This is definitely not a C++ issue but a Veins or OMNET++ issue.

**Edit 3:** Updated the MWE with the real issue. I found this out later and hence wasn't able to replicate the logic in this MWE. SORRY!

Comment: Where are the `Coord` objects created that `pos_` and `accel_` refer to? Are you sure they outlive the lifetime of the corresponding `Sender`?

Comment: Why do you store references? May be consider shared pointer instead

Comment: @UnholySheep You're right that `Coord` will not outlive `Sender`. I removed the reference to copy those objects into Sender. Even after this `CarApp` crashes. The issue is that even the `id_` variable is getting modified, which is just an `int`.

Comment: This isn't the bug, but: Always follow either the rule of 3 or the rule of 0.

Comment: you could define the members of Sender as `const`. Might show you what is changing them

Comment: It might also be insightful to run the simulation in valgrind using its memcheck tool. This might show you if some unrelated code is overwriting parts of your memory.

Comment: Did you try storing pointers (`new Sender(bsm->getSenderAddress(), other variable initializations);`) in your data structure?

Comment: I found what the issue was with my code. I did not know where the issue is and hence this MWE did not show what I really have. I have updated it to show what my problem was. Thanks all for your help!

Comment: @ChristophSommer you are right. That's what was happening. If anyone could close this, that would be great.

Comment: Thanks for contributing both the real problem and the real solution! This might be very helpful for others facing similar problems. Might I suggest writing an answer (and then marking it as the best one)? This way other people facing similar trouble are sure to find it quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this answer on @ChristophSommer 's suggestion.

When I posted this question, I did not know the real issue and hence I did not create the MWE that represented the actual code.

I later found out that I was deleting a pointer to an object in the `senderVector_`. This pointer did not allocate any memory but was merely pointing to the correct `Sender` object.

The solution was just to remove the `delete(sender);` line from the code. Since this pointer is created on the stack, it is discarded automatically once onBSM() finishes execution.